# teb_local_planner question

Tags: ros-noetic, teb-local-planner

I'm trying teb_local_planner on omni_dir robot.

[image]
https://youtu.be/AKF6wPZgCa8?si=Y_17OSZsSo7nzhfV

However, the robot moves like a car as shown in this video.

[image]
I want to moving holonomic like this picture.

my setting parameter is this.

```
TebLocalPlannerROS:
   
 # Trajectory
  
 teb_autosize: True
 dt_ref: 0.3
 dt_hysteresis: 0.1
 max_samples: 500
 global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True
 allow_init_with_backwards_motion: True
 max_global_plan_lookahead_dist: 0.5
 global_plan_viapoint_sep: -1
 global_plan_prune_distance: 1
 exact_arc_length: False
 feasibility_check_no_poses: 5
 publish_feedback: False
    
 # Robot
         
 max_vel_x: 0.4
 max_vel_x_backwards: 0.2
 max_vel_y: 0.1
 max_vel_theta: 0.3
 acc_lim_x: 0.5
 acc_lim_y: 0.2
 acc_lim_theta: 0.5
 min_turning_radius: 0.0 # omni-drive robot (can turn on place!)

 footprint_model:
  type: "circular"
  radius: 0.188 

 # GoalTolerance
    
 xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
 yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.15
 free_goal_vel: False
 complete_global_plan: True
    
 # Obstacles
    
 min_obstacle_dist: 0.25 # This value must also include our robot radius, since footprint_model is set to "point".
 inflation_dist: 0.6
 include_costmap_obstacles: False
 costmap_obstacles_behind_robot_dist: 1.0
 obstacle_poses_affected: 30
 costmap_converter_plugin: ""
 costmap_converter_spin_thread: True
 costmap_converter_rate: 5

 # Optimization
    
 no_inner_iterations: 5
 no_outer_iterations: 4
 optimization_activate: True
 optimization_verbose: False
 penalty_epsilon: 0.05
 obstacle_cost_exponent: 4
 weight_max_vel_x: 2
 weight_max_vel_y: 2
 weight_max_vel_theta: 1
 weight_acc_lim_x: 1
 weight_acc_lim_y: 1
 weight_acc_lim_theta: 1
 weight_kinematics_nh: 1 # WE HAVE A HOLONOMIC ROBOT, JUST ADD A SMALL PENALTY
 weight_kinematics_forward_drive: 1
 weight_kinematics_turning_radius: 1
 weight_optimaltime: 1 # must be > 0
 weight_shortest_path: 0
 weight_obstacle: 50
 weight_inflation: 0.2
 weight_dynamic_obstacle: 10
 weight_dynamic_obstacle_inflation: 0.2
 weight_viapoint: 1
 weight_adapt_factor: 2

 # Homotopy Class Planner

 enable_homotopy_class_planning: True
 enable_multithreading: True
 max_number_classes: 4
 selection_cost_hysteresis: 1.0
 selection_prefer_initial_plan: 0.9
 selection_obst_cost_scale: 1.0
 selection_alternative_time_cost: False
 
 roadmap_graph_no_samples: 15
 roadmap_graph_area_width: 5
 roadmap_graph_area_length_scale: 1.0
 h_signature_prescaler: 0.5
 h_signature_threshold: 0.1
 obstacle_heading_threshold: 0.45
 switching_blocking_period: 0.0
 viapoints_all_candidates: True
 delete_detours_backwards: True
 max_ratio_detours_duration_best_duration: 3.0
 visualize_hc_graph: False
 visualize_with_time_as_z_axis_scale: False

# Recovery
 
 shrink_horizon_backup: True
 shrink_horizon_min_duration: 10
 oscillation_recovery: True
 oscillation_v_eps: 0.1
 oscillation_omega_eps: 0.1
 oscillation_recovery_min_duration: 10
 oscillation_filter_duration: 10
```

What settings should I adjust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with increasing the y axis related values. First check the velocity and acceleration parameters. Is there any change on the planned path? Then I would increase the weight parameters related to y axis and observe the changes. If changing only y axis related values does not work, I would decrease x axis related values and observe the changes again. It is possible that you have selected correct values to generate a commands that can steer your robot but it is not selected as the optimum output. If none of this works, I would gradually decrease the value of the weight_kinematics_nh parameter down to zero. Also reducing the weight on the time optimization could help because x axis motion could be faster compared to y axis motion in your case (weight_optimaltime)

Comment: Movement around the x and y axes was successful.
However, there are cases where the angle rotates in a direction that requires a large amount of movement.

Comment: https://youtu.be/bx_dTixKxgY
like this video

Comment: Is this the result of changing only y axis related values? Or a combination of all of the mentioned parameters?Not sure but it has to be about the obstacles in the environment. It is trying to keep a certain distance from the obstacles. Changing parameters for the obstacles might help

Comment: I also changed other parameter values. Thanks for the advice, I'll test it.